# How to allow only particular fields of a firestore document to be accessed publicly

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Suppose I have this structure in a firestore database:

```js
collection[
  document: {
    x: 'x',
    y: 'y'
  }
]
```

and I have this firebase rule in place:

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /collection/{document} {
      allow read: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

But this rule exposes the whole `document` in the above `collection`, What I want to do is to expose only `x` field, is it possible? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firestore Rules to restrict write access to a specific field in a document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48314542/firestore-rules-to-restrict-write-access-to-a-specific-field-in-a-document)

Answer (score 28):

You can't. Security rules only work on a document-level basis, so you can't restrict read access to specific fields.

If you want to do something like you're suggesting, you'll probably need to restructure your data so that your non-public data is in a separate document. Most likely you'll want to do this by putting your private data in a subcollection. So you might end up with something like this...

```
collection: [
  document: {
    y: 'y'
    private-collection: [
      document: {
        x: 'x'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And then you'd set up your security rules like:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /collection/{document} {
      allow read: if true;
      match /private-collection/{otherdoc} {
        allow read: if someOtherRuleThatYouAddHere();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is private-collection is a subcollection name ?
and what is otherdoc refer to ?

Comment: sub-collections is a nice workaround. it is explained in the firebase docs - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#hierarchical_data

Answer (score 0):

## YOU CAN!

not do this for reading, but for updating. This is not what was asked for, but it's probably what many people came here for - including myself.

```
allow update: request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(['MyField']);
```

[Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields#restricting_fields_on_update)