# What is the Cleanest Solution to Query Data from Two Related Collections?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My current Structures looks like this

Collection Posts

```
- PostID
       - titel
       - content
       - titelimgurl
       - tags
       - timestamp
```

Now getting the Data here is easy, what I wanna achieve is splitting up the Content from the Rest so that I dont have to fetch unneeded data on my frotnpage.

So I plan to go for this structure:

Collection Posts

```
- PostID
       - titel
       - titelimgurl
       - tags
       - timestamp
```

Collection Content

```
- PostID
       - content
```

The problem is that Im not sure how to retrieve the data efficiently there for  example:

```
var postRef = db.collection("posts").doc(this.docID);

postRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        var contentRef = db.collection("content").doc(doc.id)
        contentRef.get().then(function(doc) {
            ....
         }
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

This looks overly complicated specially when assigning this data to an actual collection of posts in my Store, any ideas appreciated on how I can make this more efficient.

Comment: That's pretty standard for Firestore and NoSQL in general, since there are no "join" operations.

Comment: @DougStevenson Okay, but how do I know when its more efficient to Split the Collection up in different parts in terms of Cost. (More Reads vs Larger Reads)

Comment: It's not really possible to say without knowing a lot about the data you're storing.  If you want to know what's most efficient, you'll need to do some benchmarking and measuring of your data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query the database only once, then you shouldn't denormalize your database by creating that `content` as a top level collection. You could keep the content of the post as a property within the `PostID` document. Unlike in Firebase real-time database, where to display a list of `post` objects, you would have been downloaded the entire `posts` node, in Cloud Firestore this is not an issue anymore. So you can feel free to keep the content as a property in order to make a single query.

Comment: Oh interesting that this is possible in Firestore, I have never heard of it yet, do you have any Documentation Reference for me to read into? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand you. But you should go ahead with the first database schema, in which the content is a property within the post document. Using that option, only a read operation is involved.

Comment: Is there everything alright, have you solved the issue?

Comment: Hello, no unfortunatly I wasnt able to find out how I can query only specific parts of a Document.

Comment: I understand now what you are looking for but unfortunately you cannot query only specific parts, it's the entire document, or nothing. Please take a look at my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52295327/how-to-get-the-modified-field-or-data-from-the-doc-firebase-firestore-realtime-u/52295562#52295562)** for a better understanding.

Comment: Yep that was also why I was confused about your initial answer, I was sure there is no way to query it like that. I think I have to check what is more worth in terms of cost, 2 Reads (splitting content from the post doc in a own collection) or reading the whole content of every page. Thanks for your help so far.