# Omit fields when performing Firebase query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Is it possible to omit particular fields when performing a Firebase query?

The following query:

```
 getReferredUsers(referralId) {
    this.logger.debug(`Getting referred users by referral id ${referralId}`);
    if (referralId) {
      return this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('referredBy', '==', referralId).limit(3)).valueChanges();
    }
  }
```

Returns the following:

```
  {
    "displayName": null,
    "email": "theshizy@hotmail.co.uk",
    "emailVerified": true,
    "firstName": "James",
    "lastName": "Burton",
    "photoURL": "https://i.imgur.com/LHhAQBH.jpg",
    "referralId": "6O5qGmRQ",
    "referredBy": "cpRcYiov",
    "selectedCurrency": "GBP",
    "selectedTimezone": "(UTC) Edinburgh, London",
    "uid": "LjZ8TAb4ZGhgw2DGubbVosw8dkd2"
  }
]
```

Can I cut it down further so that it only returns the following:

```
  {
    "emailVerified": true,
    "firstName": "James",
    "lastName": "Burton",
    "photoURL": "https://i.imgur.com/LHhAQBH.jpg",
    "referralId": "6O5qGmRQ",
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The Firestore client-side SDKs always returns complete documents. There is no way to request only a part of the document with the client-side SDK, although the option does exist in the [server-side SDKs' `select` methods](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/firestore/Query.html#select-java.lang.String...-).

If you only need a part of the information, consider creating an additional collection where each document just contains the data you need. This will also allow you to more easily secure access to the different types of data.

Also see:

- [How to allow only particular fields of a firestore document to be accessed publicly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012027/how-to-allow-only-particular-fields-of-a-firestore-document-to-be-accessed-publi)
- [How to get a list of keys in Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47061903/how-to-get-a-list-of-keys-in-firestore)